# Find an element in std::set by a custom comparator

Tags: c++, stdset

I created a class `Route` which I wanted to store in an `std::set`. A Route is indexed by an Id, so what I want is to be able to have an expression like

```
class RouteTemplate
{
    Route *RouteTemplate::getRoute(const char *pId);
    Route::ptr_set mRoutes;
};

Route *RouteTemplate::getRoute(const char *pId)
{
    Route::ptr_set::const_iterator pos = mRoutes.find(pId);
    if(pos == mRoutes.end())
        return NULL;

    return *pos;
}
```

However I get a compiler error.

```
conversion from 'const char *' to 'Route *const ' not possible
```

As far as I know I have to implement the comparator, which I did.

```
class Route
{
public:
    static const size_t _id_len = 11;

    class comparator
    {
    public:
        bool operator() (const Route &oLeft, const Route &oRight) const
        {
            return oLeft < oRight;
        }
    };
    class ptr_comparator
    {
    public:
        bool operator() (const Route *oLeft, const Route *oRight) const
        {
            return (*oLeft) < (*oRight);
        }
    };

    typedef std::set<Route, Route::comparator> set;
    typedef std::set<Route *, Route::ptr_comparator> ptr_set;

public:
    Route(void);
    Route(const char *oId);
    virtual ~Route(void) {};

    inline bool operator<(const Route &oOther) const
    {
        return strncmp(mId, oOther.mId, _id_len) < 0;
    }

    inline bool operator<(const char *oId) const
    {
        if(!oId)
            return false;

        return strncmp(mId, oId, _id_len) < 0;
    }

    inline const char *getId(void) const { return mId; }
    inline void setId(const char *oId)
    {
        if(oId == NULL)
            mId[0] = 0;
        else
        {
            strncpy(mId, oId, sizeof(mId));
            mId[_id_len] = 0;
        }
    }

private:
    char mId[_id_len+1];
    // Additional members
};
```

Comment: [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

Comment: …but what's the question?!

Comment: @Biffen: `find_if` will be `O(n)` whereas it can theoretically be done in `O(log n)`

Comment: @Jarod42 OK. Is that what this is about?

Comment: @Jarod42 How do you imagine it can be done in log(n)? If you sort set by one comparator and search items by another?

Comment: @Satus You can't do that using `std::set::find`. The sort/search criteria must be the same.

Comment: @juanchopanza, but since I always reference the id, why would the search criteria be not the same? I also added the appropriate constructor, so I don't understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: @Devolus I didn't say it wasn't. I was responding to a comment from somebody else. But you should probably simplify your example into an MCVE.

Comment: @juanchopanza I know that =) That's why I was asking Jarod42.

Comment: @Satus OK. I got confused because your question has no relevance to Jarod's comment or the code posted here.

Comment: @Satus: The search use the "same" criteria, but with the *extracted* value of the key. OP may create a dummy object with the `id` value and search the dummy object, but it is not always possible.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to leverage the `template`d overload of [`std::set::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find) that was added in C++14. Before that, you could only `find()` a key of the `Key` type that is used for the `std::set`. So, the first thing to do is using a C++14 compiler.

Second, that additional overload can only function if the resulting comparison has the same semantics as would have constructing a (temporary) key and comparing it with the `std::set`s comparator. If I'm not missing anything, your comparators would qualify for this. However, to avoid accidental mistakes, you have to explicitly confirm that by giving the [`Compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) type a type member `is_transparent`.

If you can live with a temporary being created, you could explicitly ask for it.  This should work.

```
Route *RouteTemplate::getRoute(const char *pId)
{
    Route temporary_key {pId};
    Route::ptr_set::const_iterator pos = mRoutes.find(&temporary_key);
    if(pos == mRoutes.end())
        return NULL;
    return *pos;
}
```

Comment: I don't have a C++14 compiler. Currently I use Visual Studio 2010 which is about C++11 (not fully). So if I understand your comment, this will not work because that funcitionallity isd missing in the compiler? But even so, shouldn't the constructor make sure that the comparison still works? It worked for the non-pointer version at least.

Comment: You can construct a temporary `Route` from a `const char[]` (you wrote a constructor for this conversion). But you cannot construct a temporary `Route *` from a `const char *`. As far as Visual Studio is concerned, I don't know about their support but the feature was proposed by one of its maintainers so you might have a chance that it was adopted early. You'll have to consult your documentation. The official introduction was in C++14.

Comment: I tried that as well, but then I get different compiler errors. I try to create an SSCE.

Answer (score 0):

You could also overload `operator&`, to allow invoking it on temporary object. This would simplify usage o `find` method as you could create `Route` object on the fly and then apply `operator&` at this temporary.

```
class Route
{
public:
...
    Route* operator&() { return this; }
...
}
```

Then it would be valid to write `getRoute()` method like:

```
Route *RouteTemplate::getRoute(const char *pId)
{
    Route::ptr_set::const_iterator pos = mRoutes.find(&Route(pId));
    if (pos == mRoutes.end())
        return NULL;

    return *pos;
}
```